# Inserting a PDF file into Sql using VB

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, pdf

i'm building a vb application using VB2010 and SQL2008, this is application is used in the university to add lectures and assignments as a PDF file into the database.
Any help???
THX in advance

Answer (score 0):

I would seriously consider NOT storing the PDF's in the database. The benefits to storing the PDFs in the database are few, the drawbacks are many.

Better would be to store the paths/filenames and store the actual pdf's regular folder (or folders).

Comment: Thx for the advice. but the system i'm building requires that the PDFs must be stored in the database

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easier if you put the PDF's into a folder and then just store a pointer to that location in the database - The same way images are stored.

Comment: Thx for the advice. but the system i'm building requires that the PDFs must be stored in the database

Answer (score 0):

Sql 2008 has the filestream datatype, which gives you the best option for storing files on disk but being able to reference them as if they were stored directly in the database.

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895234.aspx

If you don't want to or cannot use filestream, then [varbinary(max)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188362.aspx) will work fine for storing pdf files.